# Draw Filled Shape from Four Points

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I've got four points (taken from a playing card after image processing) and I want to cover the surface of that card with a green mask. So I'm searching for a way to draw a shape that essentially has straight lines between those four points and then fills the middle of the shape with green. I was trying to use OpenCV for the task, but the rectangle method takes only two points (so unless the card is perfectly aligned the mask covers surrounding area or not enough of the card), and the fillPoly method had no effect (although I can post the code if need be). Any suggestions for a method to do this job?

Comment: there is a drawContours function where you can draw filled too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an addition to @Miki 's answer:

you can also use  [fillConvexPoly](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga906aae1606ea4ed2f27bec1537f6c5c2&gsc.tab=0) to get same result

```
Mat img = Mat::zeros( 200, 200, CV_8UC3 );
Point pts[4] = {Point(10,20),Point(60,20),Point(180,130),Point(60,150)};
fillConvexPoly( img, pts, 4, Scalar(0,255,0) );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [drawContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#drawcontours), but you need to take care of the order of points. You can do this computing the convex hull on your points.

With convex hull:

[image]

Without convex hull:

[image]

Here the C++ code, but you can easily port to Java since it's all OpenCV function calls:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
    // Some image
    Mat3b img(200, 200, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));

    vector<Point> pts{Point(10,20), Point(60,20), Point(60,150), Point(180, 130)};
    vector<Point> hull;
    convexHull(pts, hull);

    vector<vector<Point>> dummy(1, pts);
    drawContours(img, dummy, 0, Scalar(0,255,0), CV_FILLED);

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a rectangle you can find the length and breadth from the points and angle of tilt, then draw a rectangle with those specific length and breadth and tilt the rectangle.

Comment: Only issue is I'm using OpenCV tools so the corner points may not be a perfect rectangle. There isn't a tool just to draw lines between coordinates and fill the space in the middle? fillPoly sort of does it, but it needs to be a polygon.

Comment: isnt a rectangle a polygon? ;)

Comment: I thought so before I tried to draw one with fillPoly! :D