# OpenCV floodfill not consistent

Tags: java, opencv, flood-fill

Currently I'm fiddling a bit with OpenCV in Java, but I'm stuck at a problem. I can't get floodfill to work properly.

What I'm trying to do is floodfilling an area inside a rectangle. The image is pure black, with the rectangle consisting of 4 connected lines. I want to paint the rectangle white. The problem is, this does not seem to work consistenly. Even for unchanged input/code, the output may differ. Sometimes, I get a perfectly white rectangle, other times I get something like this:

[image]

Now, I tried to get my code as barebones as possible, and test it with that. The code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    points.add(new Point(40, 105));
    points.add(new Point(35, 475));
    points.add(new Point(385, 110));
    points.add(new Point(385, 485));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Mat mask = new Mat(558, 408, CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(0, 0, 0));

        Imgproc.line(mask, points.get(0), points.get(1), new Scalar(255), 1);
        Imgproc.line(mask, points.get(0), points.get(2), new Scalar(255), 1);
        Imgproc.line(mask, points.get(3), points.get(1), new Scalar(255), 1);
        Imgproc.line(mask, points.get(3), points.get(2), new Scalar(255), 1);

        Mat stub = new Mat(mask.rows() + 2, mask.cols() + 2, CvType.CV_8U);

        Imgproc.floodFill(mask, stub, Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(points.toArray(new Point[4]))).center, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("out" + i + ".png", mask);
    }
}
```

With this, the errors seems less pronounced, though sometimes I still get something like:

[image]

I'm really don't know what I'm doing wrong. It seems like I'm overlooking something? I also don't get how 75% of the images from the loop turn out perfect, but some show these artifacts, where the artifacts are random aswell...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. However, you can use [fillConvexPoly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33003913/5008845) to do this.

Comment: @Miki Sorry for the way too late answer, but this seems to work. The problem with floodfill remaines unsolved though.